# Error in adding hidden data to form

Tags: java, javascript, servlets

My **form1** looks like this,

```
<form method="post" id="myform" name="myform" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="elements">  
    <ul id="ul">
        <li>Left File&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : <input type="file" name="dataFile1" id="fileChooser1" /></li><li><br></li>
        <li>Right File&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; : <input type="file" name="dataFile2" id="fileChooser2" /></li><li><br></li>
        <li>Runner.xlsx : <input type="file" name="dataFile3" id="fileChooser3" /></li><li><br></li>
        <li><button type="button" id="execute" onclick="ValidateFile()">Click to Upload files</button></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
</form>
```

I've declared a function like this to **add hidden data** to forms,

```
function addHidden(theForm, key, value) {
var input = document.createElement('input');
input.type = 'hidden';
input.name = key;
input.value = value;
theForm.appendChild(input);
}
```

in **Validatefile()**

```
var myDivText1 = ace.edit("editor").getValue();
var theForm = document.forms['myform'];
addHidden(theForm, 'mytxt1', myDivText1);
alert(myDivText1);
document.myform.submit();
```

and in my **upload.java** servlet,

```
if (itemField.equals("dataFile1")) 
 {  //get the text of the editor here and save it

  String TEXT = request.getAttribute("mytxt1").toString();//this is being displayed as null
  System.out.println(TEXT);
  File uploadedFile = new File(fpath, fileName);
  item.write(uploadedFile);
  String f1 = "<span class='blue'>" + "Uploaded <b>left file</b> " +fileName+ "<br>" + "</span>";
  request.setAttribute("f1stat", f1);
}
```

while the alert in my Javascript function displays correct value, when I try to access this in my **upload.java** servlet it shows a null value.

I've used this function for another form too which is also it is passing the required data while this one fails, what is my mistake?

I've tried changing `getAttribute` to `getParameter` still getting Null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use `request.getParameter("mytxt1")` instead of `request.getAttribute("mytxt1")`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just tried that and it is Still displaying null value..

Comment: Can you share what you see in the alert that shows 'myDivText1'?

Comment: It alert it shows whatever I type in the `<div>` named editor.

Answer (score 0):

```
String TEXT = request.getAttribute("mytxt1").toString();
```

Being displayed as null because you don't set any attribute named "mytxt1".

You should use

```
request.getParameter("mytxt1");
```

instead because you try to get something from a form with some name variables..

Comment: I've done both. Still the vlue is null. Pl check my comment in the below question.

Answer (score 0):

Because your enctype is "multipart/form-data", you can't get anything by using request.getParameter("mytxt1"), you can try apache fileupload component.

Comment: I am not trying to upload files, I am trying to pass data from jsp to java servlet using hidden in forms

Comment: Then please remove multipart/form-data and file type input. If you have text input and file input,you should add extra code to handle them, or you can't get correct data at server side

Comment: See, I need multi part to upload files along whith that I want to pass some data

Comment: That's why you should use something like apache fileupload component

Comment: I am using that to upload files, but I want to pass data also.

Comment: See, there are two activities I wanna do
1. Upload files -> doing using apache commons
2. pass `<div>` text as hidden parameters to my servlet

Comment: My another fomr **form2** as stated above is also a multipart thingy, but yet the hidden data is being passed

Comment: 'FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
 ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
       List<FileItem> items = upload.parseRequest(request);
       Iterator<FileItem> itr = items.iterator();
       while (itr.hasNext()) {
           FileItem item = (FileItem) itr.next();
           if (item.isFormField()) {// plain text
     
     } else { // file
   
     }'